# Creating Custom logo and Description in Android Activity

Tags: android, user-interface, customization, android-tabs

I am learning and and going through a UI Development phase in android , I need to make a UI that looks exactly like I attached image below,
Please remember , this logo and Description will be available via json file , i will parse the json and will apply these two things on run time.

[Sample output screen needed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDBWr.png)

Comment: Show us what efforts you done to create that UI.

Comment: hello @jaydroider i am trying to customize AppBar in my app to achieve this , i will try to share the code in a while but please if you can guide me to the right direction that will be really great.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml take look at link. you just need to place Tablayout instead those cardviews.

Comment: Thanks @Amir , that gave me a way to move forward.